# How do I see equations in latex with certain add-on softwares with firefox?

Tags: support

I use firefox (latest version) with add-on programs like no-script and adblockplus for security reasons. The problem is that I am unable to see equations written in latex in Physics stack exchange. Even if I let no-script "temporarily allow" the current page, I am unable to see the latex equations in mathematical symbols, only the latex commands are seen like "\sqrt{...}". Please suggest how I should configure no-script so that I can see the equations properly. Thanks.

Comment: Have you allowed cdn.mathjax.org/etc? Not all scripts come from the SE domains.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to allow scripts from `stackexchange.com`, which is controlled by Stack Exchange, and from `mathjax.org`, which is controlled by the MathJax developers, in order to see equations.

The page also uses scripts from `sstatic.net`, which is also controlled by Stack Exchange, and `ajax.googleapis.com`, which is controlled by Google (but is not directly part of their tracking infrastructure). You don't need these for the equations to appear, but they do enable other functionality on the page so I recommend allowing them.